# How to fully create a new user (with proper shell settings) in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

TOP EDIT: I just figured out - it's the difference between `adduser` and `useradd`. Use `adduser` to get everything done right. You can use `useradd`, but it's older and will literally just create the user - not home directory or other expected tasks. That was my problem. :) Leaving this in case it helps someone else.

Original:

---

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Ramnode VPS - minimal, no GUI, just SSH.

When I add a user via, e.g. `adduser myusername`, it doesn't create a home directory, and the terminal is weird (I'm seeing control codes like `^[[A` for backspace, and doing `ls` doesn't show pretty colours like my main user).

I've added a home directory by running `sudo mkhomedir_helper myusername` and that did create a home directory... but that didn't solve what I assume is a lack of BASH stuff, or maybe it's the wrong shell or something.

Weirdly, this is the second user I created. The first one worked fine. I don't know what happened differently. Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Why don't you add a user in GUI in System Settings? It will do everything right without any terminal commands?

Comment: He said "no GUI".

Comment: Because GUI overhead in a VPS is undesirable. And I would think that I should be able to do everything in CLI - that's the heart of Linux anyway. And running GUI for a server is undesireable as you want to lock things down as much as possible...

Comment: Did you change anything in `/etc/adduser.conf`?

Comment: Can you now add a third user? If something goes wrong again, does `adduser` exit with 0 or a non-zero?

Comment: Sorry — figured out my problem was using `useradd` instead of `adduser`. That's why it failed.

Comment: To indicate that your problem is solved, accept an answer; don't edit the solution into the question. (You might have to wait a little while before accepting an answer.)

Comment: Thanks - I actually did both. It told me I have to wait to accept my own answer, but I also put the answer into the question. Does that seem okay? I'm new here. Thank you for your advice. I'm learning tons on many fronts. :)

Comment: For future questions I'd advise you to take a little more care when posting questions - you explicitly wrote `adduser`.

Comment: Yes, because I hadn't realized I'd made that mistake, unfortunately. I do put care into my questions. I try to give enough and accurate information. I hate people who ask stupid questions poorly, so I try not to be that person. My apologies for my mistake. My thanks to you and everyone for trying to help, and I apologize that I didn't catch what I did before I asked for help. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I just learned: Use `adduser`, not `useradd`. The former adds everything you expect (home dir, etc); the latter is older and literally just creates the user.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try is to tell `adduser` exactly what it should do:

```
sudo adduser --home /home/newuser --shell /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

## Adduser

`adduser`  and  `addgroup`  add users and groups to the system according to command    line    options    and    configuration    information    in        `/etc/adduser.conf`file.

`adduser` and `addgroup` can be run in one of five modes:

*Add a normal user:*

If  called  with  one  non-option  argument and without the `--system` or `--group` options, adduser will add a normal user.

*Add a system user:*

If called with one non-option argument and the `--system option`, `adduser`  will add a system user. If a user with the same name already exists  in  the  system uid range, `adduser` will exit with a warning.

*Add a user group:*

If `adduser` is called with the `--group` option and without  the  `--system`
option, or `addgroup` is called respectively, a user group will be added.

*Add a system group:*

If `addgroup` is called with the `--system` option, a system group will be
added.

*Add an existing user to an existing group:*

If called with two non-option arguments, `adduser` will add  an  existing user to an existing group.

*Options:*

```
--conf FILE
--disabled-login
--disabled-password
--force-badname
--gecos GECOS
--gid ID
--group
--help 
--home DIR
--shell SHELL
--ingroup GROUP
--no-create-home
--quiet
--debug
--system
--uid ID
--firstuid ID
--lastuid ID
--add_extra_groups
--version
```

*Exit values:*

`0` --- The user exists as specified.

This can have two causes: The  user was  created  by  `adduser` or the user was already present on the system before `adduser` was invoked. If `adduser` was returning 0,invoking  adduser  a  second  time  with  the same parameters as before also returns 0.

`1` --- Creating the user or group failed because it was already present  with other UID/GID than specified. The username or groupname was rejected because of  a  mismatch  with  the  configured  regular expressions. Adduser has been aborted by a signal. Or for many other yet undocumented reasons which are printed  to console  then.  You  may then consider to remove `--quiet` to make adduser more verbose.

[Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/adduser.8.html)